# Rebinding local service in other activity not working

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service

In my application I want to establish a TCP connection with a service and bind this service to every activity where it is needed. It gets started in my Login activity and everything is working like it should. Here is the code:

```
private TCPService mService;
private boolean mBound = false;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TCPService.class);
    startService(intent);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
}

/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        TCPService.LocalBinder binder = (TCPService.LocalBinder)service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

Now I want to bind the service in another activity by using almost the same code just without `startService(intent);` But the mBound is never set to true and I can't access the service functions like it is intented.

Here is the implementation of the service:

```
public class TCPService extends Service {

    private final IBinder myBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public TCPService getService() {
            return TCPService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return myBinder;
    }
}
```

What am I missing out? Is there anything I should check that may cause this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `startService` if you're binding to it, although I suspect this is not the cause. Did you override your service's `onBind` method to return your binder instance? By default the implementation will return null, which means that binding to the service will not be allowed.

Comment: Yes I override the `onBind` method, please see the code in my updated question. `startService` is only called once when the service is first needed and should onlay be bound to other activities afterwards.